# How to deconstruct types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Directory deconstruction is like this:

[image]

First, I exposed some submodules in the repository module:
repository/index.ts

```js
    import { CachePlugin } from "./plugins/cache-plugin";
    import { EsPlugin } from "./plugins/es-plugin";
    const plugin = { EsPlugin, CachePlugin };
    export { FindResultPageNext, plugin };
```

Second,I expose all submodules (including types) of the repository to index.ts as a collection
index.ts

```js
    import * as repository from "./repository";
    export { repository };
```

If I were to use EsPlugin, the reference would be very long,The introduction of other file:
test.ts

```js
   class A extends repository.plugin.EsPlugin {
   }
```

This is just an example. In real use, there are modules with deeper nesting, such as respository.xxx.xxx.a. Introduce a module. Is there a good way to solve this problem? Do you expect to directly refer to a?

Comment: This question is really difficult to describe. I don’t know if you can understand my question. I look forward to your answers. If you have any questions, you can learn more.

Comment: How would you rather access them? What's your goal?

Comment: I don't really understand the question either. Awaiting better explanation, just want to say  you don't need to first import * to export it. You could just say for example `export * from './repository'`

Comment: @AlexWayne I expect the result to use types like destructuring variables. I know this is impossible, but my confusion is that it’s too troublesome to introduce each time.

```javscript
       const {plugin} = respository;
```

Comment: @funkizer I want to expose the final index.ts, but to ensure the structural relationship between the modules, so I did not use export * from "respository", I expect export {respository}

Comment: import {repository,routeDeco } from "#kernel";
const {get,post,put,del,route} = routeDeco;
`
class Facade {
  
  @get('api/users')
  getUsers(){

  }
} 
`
Using get like this will be more elegant than routeDeco.get, the type can only be routeDeco.interface but not deconstruction const {interface} = routeDeco

Answer (score 0):

When exporting, you can export a default export:

```
export default { data: 123 }
```

Or a named export:

```
export const data = { data: 123 }

// or

const data = { data: 123 }
export { data } // equivalent
```

---

When importing, you can import a default export:

```
import data from './data'
```

Or a named export:

```
import { data } from './data'
```

Or a named export that you renamed:

```
import { data as myData } from './data'
```

Or all named exports wrapped up into a single object:

```
import * as data from './data'
```

---

What you cannot do is use destructuring in an `import` statement. If a named export isn't specific enough, then you need to drill in the imported value:

```
import { something } from './something'
const myValue = something.foo.bar.baz
// now use mValue instead of something.foo.bar.baz
```

But you are the one that added this nesting. And this approach of importing and re-exporting is usually not advised. It makes it so there are many ways to import the same value, which can be confusing.

For example, here's three ways to import the exact same value.

```
import { CachePlugin } from "./plugins/cache-plugin";

import { plugin } from './repository'
const { CachePlugin } = plugin

import { respository } from '.'
const { plugin: { CachePlugin } } = repository
```

That's not great.

The point is that this:

```
import * as repository from "./repository";
export { repository };
```

Is *generally* a bad pattern without a good reason. You now have an alternate and deeply nested way to import the exact same values that could be imported from another file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but you are talking about the export of values. If the file has both values ​​and types, then your approach seems to be unable to solve it.


```typescript
export const data = 123;

export interface Data {
   id:number;
   name: string;
}
```

Comment: You can always just `import { Data }` from './path/to/deep/file'

Comment: Since our code has to be handed over to other developers for secondary development, we compress all directories into one file: index, so ./path/to/file cannot be used,Thank you for your answer, I think there may be no elegant solution at all 